# Make card bootstrap same height with different value response json

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a json response array like this

```
 var response2 = {
 "response": {
    "Data1": [{
      codeImage: "605313c59050dc5fc1f3372c"
      created_by: "23"
      form_name: "default"
      location: "station 1"
      image_file: "605313c59050dc5fc1f3372c123a213.png"
      image_url: "https://mysite:8241/products/view?code=605313c59050dc5fc1f3372c123a213"
      _id: "605313c59050dc5fc1f3372c",
    }],
    "Data2": [{
      codeImage: "605313fe3cdf045fbcf14be5"
      created_by: "23"
      form_name: "default"
      location: "testing testing testing testing testing"
      image_file: "605313c59050dc5fc1f3372c123a213.png"
      image_url: "https://mysite:8241/products/view?code=605313c59050dc5fc1f3372c123a213"
      _id: "605313fe3cdf045fbcf14be5",
    }]
   }}
```

I want to display the data above using `card` bootstrap. I 've tried using `append`, but the problem is the height card is not same because `location` in `Data1` and `Data2` have different length.

Here's the `append` code

```
for (var i = 0; i < response2.response.length; i++)
{
    var location = response2.response[i].location
    var image= response2.response[i].image_url
    var form_name = response2.response[i].form_name

    var showImage= 
     '<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-xl-4 col-padding" style="padding-right:0px; padding-left:20px; display: table; width: 100%;">'+
          '<div class="card card-custom card-stretch gutter-b card-padding">'+
              '<div class="d-flex align-items-center row">'+
                  '<div class="col">'+
                      '<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xl-12">'+
                            '<div class="text-muted mt-1">Location</div>'+
                            '<p class="text-dark font-weight-bolder font-size-lg mt-2">'+location+'</p>'+
                      '</div>'+
                      '<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xl-12">'+
                            '<div class="text-muted mt-1">Form</div>'+
                            '<p class="text-dark font-weight-bolder font-size-lg mt-2">'+form_name+'</p>'+
                      '</div>'+
                  '</div>'+
                  '<div class="col">'+
                      '<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xl-12">'+
                             '<img src="'+image+'" alt="" class="image-img">'+
                      '</div>'+
                  '</div>'+
              '</div>'+
              '<div class="row justify-content-center btn-margin" style="margin-left:-25px">'+
                    '<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-xl-4">'+
                         '<button class="btn btn-xl btn-light btn-full-width" style="margin-right:10px"><i class="fas fa-print"></i> Show Data</button>'+
                     '</div>'+
                     '<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-xl-4">'+
                         '<button class="btn btn-xl btn-primary btn-full-width" style="margin-right:10px"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i> Edit</button>'+
                     '</div>'+
                     '<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-xl-4" >'+
                          '<button class="btn btn-xl btn-danger btn-full-width" style="margin-right:10px; width: 100px;"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> Delete</button>'+
                     '</div>'+
              '</div>'+
          '</div>'+
    '</div>';
    $("#imagepadding").append(showImage);
 }
```

Here's the html that `imagepadding` card need to show

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column-fluid">
    <div class="container addon-padding">
        <div class="row" id="imagepadding">    
        
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried using `h-100 card-body` in `<div class="card card-custom card-stretch gutter-b card-padding` but the result is same.

Do you know how to make my `card` bootstrap have same height ?

Thank you

Comment: Your code doesn't work, your JSON data is invalid. Please fix these things first and post a minimal reproducible code. If your main concern is about CSS, then don't post code like this that is totally unnecessary, Rater, post the rendered html from your code that has the CSS issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're looking for a [**`card-deck`**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/card/#card-decks). When you wrap cards in a `<div class="card-deck">`, those cards get automatically sized with equal height.

---

**UPDATE:** In addition to a `.card-deck` wrapper, put the buttons in a `.card-footer` to align the button positions. The demo below puts the buttons in a `<div class="card-footer bg-white border-0">` to align them at the bottom of each card.

Note that bootstrap only fixes the heights when cards are side-by-side (in a multi-column breakpoint). In the single `col-12` layout, bootstrap will not adjust the heights because everything is in 1 column.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- wrap .cards in .card-deck to make them the same height -->
<div class="card-deck">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <p class="card-text">station 1</p>
    </div>
    <!-- put buttons in .card-footer to align across cards -->
    <div class="card-footer bg-white border-0">
      <button class="btn btn-light border">Show</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
      <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <p class="card-text">testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing</p>
    </div>
    <!-- put buttons in .card-footer to align across cards -->
    <div class="card-footer bg-white border-0">
      <button class="btn btn-light border">Show</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
      <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @tdy, I've tried, button the height / button position is not same. In `station 1` card, `save` `edit` and `delete` button still not same position like in card `testing`

Comment: In addition to wrapping cards in a `card deck`, put the buttons in a `card-footer` within each card. That will align the buttons within each card. I updated the answer and the embedded  demo.

Comment: If that's still not what you're looking for, please make a [minimal code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that can be run inside SO. As mentioned in the comments, we can’t test with the code you posted so it’s hard to understand the problem/solution. If you can’t make a minimal reproducible example, you could also take some screenshots or sketch some pictures showing the current layout vs desired layout.